# How to ensure access to Delve via JS/SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, delve

I'm working on an SPFx web part which displays the company's employees from a list. One of the primary functions of the web part is to pull a couple of Users' current profile pictures from Delve.

This works fine if I have visited Delve recently, but if I haven't, the page doesn't load the picture. This appears to be because of a need for an active connection with Delve when the page loads. Is there a way to ping Delve before the web part renders the HTML to ensure that End Users will see the Profile Pictures?

**Edit**

The Code which references the image is:

```
let pPic = "background-image: url(https://nam.delve.office.com/mt/v3/people/profileimage?userId=PLACEHOLDER&size=L)";
```

and this is inserted to the HTML using:

```
<td rowspan="2" class="${styles.prof}" style="${pPic}">
```

Also, the `PLACEHOLDER` referenced in pPic is replaced with the User's email address between these two snips.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet that you are using to pull data ? I might have an idea.

Comment: I've added the code as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing this issue because the page on which your webpart is present would be something like `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/SitePages/abc.aspx`, whereas the image you are using is from `https://nam.delve.office.com`. This means that they are different domains which causes the browser to restrict cross-data interaction.

So, to get around this issue, you need to use the `userphoto.aspx` URL. It is a proxy page used by Microsoft themselves to get around this issue.

Modify your code as below:

```
let pPic = `background-image: url(${this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl}/_layouts/15/
userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname=${encodeURIComponent(<Email>)}`;
```

Make the necessary changes as per your variable names and user's email address.

Comment: One of the user's photos isn't loading properly. Is this link pulling from Delve's profile picture?

Comment: is it accessible in browser ? The profile photos are stored in User Profile Service, which is where we are pulling data from. What's the issue with this user ?

Comment: A placeholder image is downloaded when I manually navigate to the url.

Comment: It usually means that the user has not uploaded delve image. If the user has uploaded an image, it will take some time to get populated in the User profile, usually from couple of hours to 2-3 days. Has the user uploaded image in delve ?

Comment: They do have an image in Delve, however while I am currently looking at their page I'm noticing that on the Left Hand Navigation, their image is the placeholder and on their profile there is an image?

Comment: So I believe I've found the source of the problem. We have (at)abc.com and (at)def.com as email addresses. This user's image is syncing with one of the addresses and not the other. Based on a quick check with other users, If I convert the email from (at)def.com back to (at)abc.com, then render that it should work fine for all users. Thanks for the help!